# Moving player in Subway Surf like game using left/right swipe

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing endless runner game like subway surfer in Unity.
I want to move my player, smoothly on swipe left or right.
How can do it?
Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwipeScript3 : MonoBehaviour {

private Touch initialTouch = new Touch();
private float distance = 0;
private bool hasSwiped = false;
//Quaternion targetx = Quaternion.Euler(0, -3f, 0);
//Quaternion targety = Quaternion.Euler(0, 3f, 0);

void FixedUpdate()
{
    foreach(Touch t in Input.touches)
    {
        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            initialTouch = t;
        }
        else if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && !hasSwiped)
        {
            float deltaX = initialTouch.position.x - t.position.x;
            float deltaY = initialTouch.position.y - t.position.y;
            distance = Mathf.Sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY));
            bool swipedSideways = Mathf.Abs(deltaX) > Mathf.Abs(deltaY);

            if (distance > 50f)
            {
                if (swipedSideways && deltaX > 0) //swiped left
                {

                    //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetx, Time.deltaTime * 0.8f);
                    this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -3f, 0)*Time.deltaTime);
                    //transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position,new Vector3(transform.position.x+5f,transform.position.y,transform.position.z),Time.deltaTime*2f );
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Time.deltaTime * 5f);
                }
                else if (swipedSideways && deltaX <= 0) //swiped right
                {
                    //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targety, Time.deltaTime * 0.8f);
                    this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 3f, 0)*Time.deltaTime);
                    //transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Time.deltaTime * f);
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position,new Vector3(transform.position.x+5f,transform.position.y,transform.position.z),Time.deltaTime*5f );
                }
                else if (!swipedSideways && deltaY > 0) //swiped down
                {
                    //this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2f, 0));
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position,new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,transform.position.z-5f),Time.deltaTime*2f );
                }
                else if (!swipedSideways && deltaY <= 0)  //swiped up
                {
                    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x, 0, this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);
                    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 400f, 0));
                    Debug.Log ("Swiped Up");
                }

                hasSwiped = true;
            }

        }
        else if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            initialTouch = new Touch();
            hasSwiped = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please consider changing the title to something more readable like: _How to move player smoothly on swipe left or right (endless runner game like subway surfer)?_. As your post has been edited already I can't sadly propose it (<2k rep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Vector3.Slerp(Vector3 StartPosition, Vector3 DestinationPosition, float Number)`

- `Number` is between 0 and 1 and it indicates where will be the position of your object between `StartPosition` and `DestinationPosition`.
- Lets say `Number = 0.0f;`: your object will be at `StartPosition`.
- If `Number = 0.5f;`: your object will be between `StartPosition` and `DestinationPosition`.
- You need to increase the `Number` value from 0 to 1 when swipe action is performed.
- The faster you increase the "Number" value, the faster your object will move towards Destination.
- You should set you `StartPosition` once when the swipe action begins, not give your `transform.position` repeatedly in your `Vector3.Slerp()` function.

You can find an example [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) in Unity Docs.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: EmreE i applied your approach but still no result my player teleprote not moving smoothly...

Comment: The few reasons i could think that your player is teleporting;
-Are you increasing your "Number" value too fast?

Lets say you have 3 positions; Left , Mid and Right.

You want to move the player from mid to left.
You give the start position as mid position(which is transform.pos in this case) and destinationPostion as Left Position.

If you increase "Number" value slow enough , your player should go to mid to left position smoothly.

Comment: And can you try same thing with Vector3.Lerp. Let me know the result. @hamzamustafa