# Unity - Quaternion.Slerp instantly rotating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am trying to have my object smoothly rotate on the Z axis from 0 to 180, back and forth on every button press.

The **Quaternion.Slerp** setup i'm using does not smoothly rotate to the target rotation, rather it instantly jumps to a number close to it. After many button presses that call the Quaternion.Slerp, it it finally halfs works in that it goes from 0 to 180, but still instantly and not smoothly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public bool movePlayer;
    private float maxMoveSpeed;
    public float waitToMove;
    Rigidbody2D thisRigidbody;


    //SCOOP variables
    private GameObject scoop;
    private GameObject scoopRotation;

    Quaternion currentScoopRotation;
    public Quaternion targetScoopRotation;
    Quaternion lastScoopRotation;
    public float scoopRotateTime;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        thisRigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        maxMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;

        //SCOOP finders
        scoop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Scoop");
        currentScoopRotation = scoop.transform.rotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if(movePlayer)
        thisRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed,  thisRigidbody.velocity.y);    


        //Rotates SCOOP using Quaternions + Spacebar
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { 
            lastScoopRotation = currentScoopRotation;
            scoop.transform.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (currentScoopRotation, targetScoopRotation, scoopRotateTime * Time.time);
            currentScoopRotation = targetScoopRotation;
            targetScoopRotation = lastScoopRotation;
            changeMoveDirection ();
        }
    }

    void changeMoveDirection()
    {
            moveSpeed *= -1;
    }

     IEnumerator changeDirectionCO()
    {
        //thisRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (0f,0f);
        //moveSpeed = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitToMove);
        moveSpeed *= -1;
    }


}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be dividing by the time to rotate? 
  Time.time/scoopRotateTime

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just tried your suggestion. Still not working out. I should've mentioned my scoopRotateTime is at .1f 
But I tried 1, .2f, 100, 5, and other number to divide/ multiply by time and still the same unwanted results.

Comment: You might also check ms versus seconds if its moving faster than expected. When debugging you should always keep breaking the problem down further.  Does parameter 3 vary from 0 to 1 smoothly in the time you expect? Does the return value make sense even if the rendering doesn't?  Are you setting the current value to the target and ignoring the lerp?
 currentScoopRotation = targetScoopRotation

Comment: Ah true about ms/ seconds. I'll tinker around with this more. Thank you!

Comment: When you lerp/slerp you usually go from initial to final, not current to final. You'll get non linear rotation speed otherwise.  Quaternion.Lerp (initialScoopRotation, targetScoopRotation, scoopRotateTime * Time.time).   Are you doing the full 180 in one lerp? Think about linear interpolation on a unit sphere. if you go between close points on the sphere the linear interpolation doesn't vary much from the arc.  If you do a full 180 you go through the center of the sphere... and your orientation suddenly flips when you pass through the center point.

Comment: I've explained similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153617/moving-player-in-subway-surf-like-game-using-left-right-swipe/42154529#42154529) before about slerp. Can you check it ? It may give you and idea. First thing that comes to my mind is if your slerp is done instant, you probably increasing the 3rd parameter of lerp/slerp too fast. Also as first parameter you need to give startRotation not currentRotation