# Why does my character/camera stutter in Unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, 2d

Ever since I've added this new camera script, my character (which the camera is trying to follow) keeps on stuttering when it is moving. If I keep the character still, then it won't stutter anymore.

[Here's a video of what I mean.](https://youtu.be/UZO3xeDoCRI)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{   
public Transform lookat;

private bool smooth = true;
private float smoothSpeed = 0.1f;
private Vector3 offset = new Vector3 (0, 0, -6.5f); 

void LateUpdate() {

    Vector3 desiredPosition = lookat.transform.position + offset;

    if (smooth) {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    } else {
        transform.position = desiredPosition;
    }

}
```

}

Please help - it's driving me crazy!
EDIT: Also ignore the error at the bottom - it's part of something else I'm working on.

EDIT2: Never mind, turning on interpolation in rigidbody2d fixed it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you moving the player?

Comment: My suggestion is check how Vector3.Lerp works. I've explained one in the past to a question required Vector3.Lerp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153617/moving-player-in-subway-surf-like-game-using-left-right-swipe/42154529#42154529)

Answer (score 0):

**The studdering is not caused due to the** ***Update()*** **function!**

The stuttering is probably caused because of the *Lerp()* function, you would rather use the *SmoothDamp()*.

**Like this**

```
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I also found that turning on Interpolation in the Rigidbody2D fixed the problem aswell.